# Why does my allreduce using ring algorithm not work？

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

I am implementing mpi function in allreduce in mpi using ring algorithm. I write function `Ring_Allreduce` and `Naive_Allreduce` is a naive implement and also use `MPI_Allreduce` for test. And below is my code:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

#define EPS 1e-8

namespace ch = std::chrono;

void Ring_Allreduce(void* sendbuf,
                    void* recvbuf,
                    int n,
                    MPI_Comm comm,
                    int comm_sz,
                    int my_rank) {
    float* send = (float*)sendbuf;
    float* recv = (float*)recvbuf;
    MPI_Request req[2];
    MPI_Status status[2];
    int len = n / comm_sz;
    for (int i = 0; i < comm_sz - 1; i++) {
        int start = my_rank - i;
        if (start < 0)
            start += comm_sz;
        int s = 0;
        if (my_rank == comm_sz - 1)
            s = 0;
        else
            s = my_rank + 1;
        MPI_Isend(send + start * len, len, MPI_FLOAT, s, i, comm, &req[0]);
        int rec = 0;
        if (my_rank == 0)
            rec = comm_sz - 1;
        else
            rec = my_rank - 1;
        int end = 0;
        if (start == 0)
            end = comm_sz - 1;
        else
            end = start - 1;
        MPI_Irecv(recv + end * len, len, MPI_FLOAT, rec, i, comm, &req[1]);
        for (int j = end * len; j < len; j++) {
            send[j] += recv[j];
        }
        MPI_Waitall(2, req, status);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < comm_sz - 1; i++) {
        int start = my_rank + 1 - i;
        if (start < 0)
            start += comm_sz;
        int s = 0;
        if (my_rank == comm_sz - 1)
            s = 0;
        else
            s = my_rank + 1;
        MPI_Isend(recv + start * len, len, MPI_FLOAT, s, i, comm, &req[0]);
        int rec = 0;
        if (my_rank == 0)
            rec = comm_sz - 1;
        else
            rec = my_rank - 1;
        int end = 0;
        if (start == 0)
            end = comm_sz - 1;
        else
            end = start - 1;
        MPI_Irecv(recv + end * len, len, MPI_FLOAT, rec, i, comm, &req[1]);
        memcpy(recv + end * len, send + end * len, len * sizeof(float));
        MPI_Waitall(2, req, status);
    }
}

// reduce + bcast
void Naive_Allreduce(void* sendbuf,
                     void* recvbuf,
                     int n,
                     MPI_Comm comm,
                     int comm_sz,
                     int my_rank) {
    MPI_Reduce(sendbuf, recvbuf, n, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_SUM, 0, comm);
    MPI_Bcast(recvbuf, n, MPI_FLOAT, 0, comm);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int ITER = atoi(argv[1]);
    int n = atoi(argv[2]);
    float* mpi_sendbuf = new float[n];
    float* mpi_recvbuf = new float[n];
    float* naive_sendbuf = new float[n];
    float* naive_recvbuf = new float[n];
    float* ring_sendbuf = new float[n];
    float* ring_recvbuf = new float[n];

    MPI_Init(nullptr, nullptr);
    int comm_sz;
    int my_rank;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm_sz);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

    srand(time(NULL) + my_rank);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        mpi_sendbuf[i] =
            static_cast<float>(rand()) / static_cast<float>(RAND_MAX);
    memcpy(naive_sendbuf, mpi_sendbuf, n * sizeof(float));
    memcpy(ring_sendbuf, mpi_sendbuf, n * sizeof(float));

    // warmup and check
    MPI_Allreduce(mpi_sendbuf, mpi_recvbuf, n, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_SUM,
                  MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    Naive_Allreduce(naive_sendbuf, naive_recvbuf, n, MPI_COMM_WORLD, comm_sz,
                    my_rank);
    Ring_Allreduce(ring_sendbuf, ring_recvbuf, n, MPI_COMM_WORLD, comm_sz,
                   my_rank);
    bool correct = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        if (abs(mpi_recvbuf[i] - ring_recvbuf[i]) > EPS) {
            correct = false;
            break;
        }

    if (correct) {
        auto beg = ch::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (int iter = 0; iter < ITER; ++iter)
            MPI_Allreduce(mpi_sendbuf, mpi_recvbuf, n, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_SUM,
                          MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        auto end = ch::high_resolution_clock::now();
        double mpi_dur =
            ch::duration_cast<ch::duration<double>>(end - beg).count() *
            1000;  // ms

        beg = ch::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (int iter = 0; iter < ITER; ++iter)
            Naive_Allreduce(naive_sendbuf, naive_recvbuf, n, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
                            comm_sz, my_rank);
        end = ch::high_resolution_clock::now();
        double naive_dur =
            ch::duration_cast<ch::duration<double>>(end - beg).count() *
            1000;  // ms

        beg = ch::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (int iter = 0; iter < ITER; ++iter)
            Ring_Allreduce(ring_sendbuf, ring_recvbuf, n, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
                           comm_sz, my_rank);
        end = ch::high_resolution_clock::now();
        double ring_dur =
            ch::duration_cast<ch::duration<double>>(end - beg).count() *
            1000;  // ms

        if (my_rank == 0) {
            std::cout << "Correct." << std::endl;
            std::cout << "MPI_Allreduce:   " << mpi_dur << " ms." << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Naive_Allreduce: " << naive_dur << " ms."
                      << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Ring_Allreduce:  " << ring_dur << " ms." << std::endl;
        }
    } else if (my_rank == 0)
        std::cout << "Wrong!" << std::endl;

    delete[] mpi_sendbuf;
    delete[] mpi_recvbuf;
    delete[] naive_sendbuf;
    delete[] naive_recvbuf;
    delete[] ring_sendbuf;
    delete[] ring_recvbuf;
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I implement Ring_Allreduce and others are for testing.
I use command:

```
mpicxx allreduce.cpp -O3 -std=c++11 -o allreduce
mpirun -np 4 ./allreduce 10 100000000
```

and the restlt is:

```
===================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   PID 7548 RUNNING AT Jeff
=   EXIT CODE: 139
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
===================================================================================
YOUR APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Segmentation fault (signal 11)
This typically refers to a problem with your application.
Please see the FAQ page for debugging suggestions
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Use print statement to found out where the code bombs. And if you want to write good C++, do not use malloc/new'ed arrays.

Comment: first, make sure trivial cases such as `mpirun -np 1 ./allreduce 1 1` and `mpirun -np 2 ./allreduce 2 2` work as expected. If they don't, then run your program by hand and see what goes wrong.